# Magento2.4 - How to filter out states?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

How do we filter out states from the shipping address dropdown menu on checkout?

Comment: Can you please describe in detail, what you are looking?

Comment: To restrict certain states from shipping dropdown.  I want to allow all the states for billing addresses, but I have a list of states I need to ban from being shipped to.

Comment: You need to use the Event Observer here, to restrict this one.